DNS queries not going through AdGuard Home after configuring router DNS?
I'm running AdGuard Home in Docker on Ubuntu 22.04 with IP 192.168.1.3 (static ip for my computer which run AdGuard Home). When testing with nslookup google.com, queries aren't going through AdGuard despite router configuration. I have read carefully on the documents
version: '3'
services:
  adguardhome:
    image: adguard/adguardhome
    container_name: adguardhome
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - adguard_work:/opt/adguardhome/work
      - adguard_conf:/opt/adguardhome/conf
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "67:67/udp"
      - "68:68/udp"
      - "80:80/tcp"
      - "443:443/tcp"
      - "443:443/udp"
      - "3000:3000/tcp"
      - "853:853/tcp"
      - "784:784/udp"
      - "853:853/udp"
      - "8853:8853/udp"
      - "5443:5443/tcp"
      - "5443:5443/udp"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
volumes:
 adguard_work:
 adguard_conf:

networks:
  adguard_net:
    driver: bridge

I have checked log on docker container.
2024/12/30 17:28:12.165187 ERROR response received addr=149.112.112.10:53 proto=udp status="exchanging with 149.112.112.10:53 over udp: read udp 172.20.0.2:60344->149.112.112.10:53: i/o timeout"
2024/12/30 17:28:12.165203 ERROR response received addr=9.9.9.10:53 proto=udp status="exchanging with 9.9.9.10:53 over udp: read udp 172.20.0.2:56324->9.9.9.10:53: i/o timeout"
2024/12/30 17:28:12.165187 ERROR response received addr=149.112.112.10:53 proto=udp status="exchanging with 149.112.112.10:53 over udp: read udp 172.20.0.2:59324->149.112.112.10:53: i/o timeout"
2024/12/30 17:28:12.165246 ERROR response received addr=9.9.9.10:53 proto=udp status="exchanging with 9.9.9.10:53 over udp: read udp 172.20.0.2:55067->9.9.9.10:53: i/o timeout"
2024/12/30 17:28:12.165343 [error] dnsproxy: exchange failed upstream=https://dns10.quad9.net:443/dns-query question=";homewifi3.viettel.vn.\tIN\t AAAA" duration=20.001750716s err="failed to init http client: initializing http transport: bootstrapping https://dns10.quad9.net:443/dns-query: dialing \"dns10.quad9.net:443\": resolving hostname: dialing [2620:fe::fe:10]:53 over udp: dial udp [2620:fe::fe:10]:53: connect: cannot assign requested address\ndialing [2620:fe::fe:10]:53 over udp: dial udp [2620:fe::fe:10]:53: connect: cannot assign requested address\ndialing [2620:fe::10]:53 over udp: dial udp [2620:fe::10]:53: connect: cannot assign requested address\ndialing [2620:fe::10]:53 over udp: dial udp [2620:fe::10]:53: connect: cannot assign requested address\nexchanging with 149.112.112.10:53 over udp: read udp 172.20.0.2:60344->149.112.112.10:53: i/o timeout\nexchanging with 149.112.112.10:53 over udp: read udp 172.20.0.2:59324->149.112.112.10:53: i/o timeout\nexchanging with 9.9.9.10:53 over udp: read udp 172.20.0.2:56324->9.9.9.10:53: i/o timeout\nexchanging with 9.9.9.10:53 over udp: read udp 172.20.0.2:55067->9.9.9.10:53: i/o timeout"
2024/12/30 17:28:12.165456 [error] dnsproxy: exchange failed upstream=https://dns10.quad9.net:443/dns-query question=";homewifi3.viettel.vn.\tIN\t A" duration=20.0017958s err="failed to init http client: timeout exceeded: 20.001791258s"

This is my config on router.

IP Server (Macos) run AdguardHome.

AdGuard Dashboard

Question: Why aren't DNS queries going through AdGuard Home and how can I fix this?
